# Running one single SQL query over many databases on one single server

Tags: sql-server, database, search, stored-procedures

I have a query to check my procedures, as follows:

```
DECLARE @SearchTerm VARCHAR(MAX) = 'INSERT' -- Just an example

SELECT ROUTINE_NAME [Procedure]
, SPECIFIC_CATALOG [Database]
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE SUBSTRING(ROUTINE_DEFINITION, 54, 20) LIKE '%'+@SearchTerm+'%'
AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
ORDER BY [Procedure]
```

Example output:

```
Procedure     Database
pGetAnimals   Zoo
pGetGreens    Food
pGetBeans     Food
pGetChocolate Food
```

Trouble is, my knowledge restricts me to opening a query for each database on a server.

What I would like is to run the query over all the databases on a server, either as; a single select statement, or for the results to populate a temporary table.

I'm sure it's possible.

Does anyone know a neat trick to do this?

Comment: You could use dynamic sql and sys.databases for this pretty easily. Or you could use the procedure here to loop through all the databases. https://sqlblog.org/2010/12/29/a-more-reliable-and-more-flexible-sp_msforeachdb

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code:

```
DECLARE @SearchTerm VARCHAR(MAX) = 'INSERT' -- Just an example

USE master

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME='MyProcedures') DROP TABLE MyProcedures
CREATE TABLE MyProcedures([Procedure] VARCHAR(512) NULL,[Database] VARCHAR(64) NULL)

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'USE ?  

INSERT INTO master.dbo.MyProcedures
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME [Procedure]
, SPECIFIC_CATALOG [Database]
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE SUBSTRING(ROUTINE_DEFINITION, 54, 20) LIKE ''%' + @SearchTerm + '%''
AND ROUTINE_TYPE = ''PROCEDURE''
ORDER BY [Procedure]
';

SELECT * FROM MyProcedures
```

Note: The main SQL is populating a table on the master database, and is VARCHAR based.